# Use edge during traverse in while for Orientdb

Tags: orientdb

I have a database with classes users, groups, and networks. Users can have out_ edges to groups or networks. Groups can have out_ edges only to networks. There are three different types of edges, admin, write, and read.

I want to be able to retrieve networks a user has permissions to. The easiest way to do this would be to look at the edges connecting users, groups, and networks. I am trying the following:

```
select from (traverse out() from <User Record RID> 
                            while $depth <=2 
                            AND ( (@class = 'group' AND <edgeType = write>
                                 OR (@class = 'network' AND <edgeType = read>) 
                                 OR @class ='user') ) 
       where @class = 'network'
```

How can I write the boolean

```
 <edgeType = write>
```

in the context of the of the current traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a vertex (you're jumping from vertex to vertex skipping edges with out()) You can use inE() to get the incoming edge and outE(). So try to add:

```
inE().@class = 'WriteEdge'
```

If you have one class per edge type (suggested). Or you can also do:

```
inE('WriteEdge').size() > 0
```

Otherwise you could not skip edges in traversal but traverse vertex and edge, adding WHILE conditions that match edges and vertices. Example:

```
select from (traverse outV(), outE() from <User Record RID> 
                        while $depth <=4 
                        AND ... )
   where @class = 'network'
```

Another option is move forward and check back the traversed vertices and edges with the functions:

- traversedVertex()
- traversedEdge()
- traversedElement()

Use -1 to get last traversed. -2 the one before last, etc.